# How to compute geodesics in upper half-plane?

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Given two points in the upper half-plane with the usual hyperbolic metric, the geodesic between them is found by drawing a circle through them that crosses the real axis at right angles. However, if I give you coordinates for the points, how do I construct such a circle explicitly? I guess this becomes a question in classical plane geometry, but I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of the circle lies on the real axis, and also on the perpendicular bisector of the two points, so...

Comment: What if one of the points lies on the interior of the upper half-plane and the other on the real axis. How to describe the geodesic that goes from the interior point to the boundary point (in infinite time)?

Comment: I thought you wanted a Euclidean geometry construction. The same thing works: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vu9Ry.png

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I have solved the geodesics in terms of an implicit equation as
\begin{align}
(x^2+y^2)t-xd-s=0\,,
\end{align}
where $t$, $d$ and $s$ are first integrals given by three killing vectors of the geometry. This is also a half circle in the upper half-plane in the Euclidean sense, when $t \neq 0$, which you have mentioned. One can also write down this implicit equation directly, knowing that the geodesics are half-circles (and lines parallel to the $y$-axis).

Now that you give me two points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$ that lie on a geodesic, I can insert them into the implicit equation and solve for the first integrals. One solution is
\begin{align}
t &= -x_1 + x_2\,, \\
d &= -x_1^2 + x_2^2 - y_1^2 + y_2^2\,, \\
s &= x_1 x_2 (x_1 - x_2) - x_1 y_2^2 + x_2 y_1^2\,.
\end{align}
This solution also works for $x_1 = x_2$.